# How to display the line count on a grid in ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am developing an ExtJs application; and in this application it is possible to add new lines dynamically to a grid. However, I do not know how I can number the lines as they are added. Can anyone provide me with some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the RowNumberer class in the documentation.

```
columns: [
    {xtype: 'rownumberer'},
    {text: "Company", flex: 1, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'company'},
    {text: "Price", width: 120, sortable: true, renderer: Ext.util.Format.usMoney, dataIndex: 'price'},
    {text: "Change", width: 120, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'change'},
    {text: "% Change", width: 120, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'pctChange'},
    {text: "Last Updated", width: 120, sortable: true, renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'), dataIndex: 'lastChange'}
]
```

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.RowNumberer

Comment: This solution worked, but as I add lines numbering that appears is '1', then I do the reload the page, back to the numbering correct.

Comment: You could try to get the current grid view by using the getView() method and trigger the refresh() method. grid.getView().refresh(). Another way is to reload the store. grid.getStore().reload(). Hope it helps.